# Open dev tools with focus on current file

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

When working with Google dev tools, I can open it with <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, it will bring up the panel on the sources tab. However, the html file that's open in browser (and part of my workspace) isn't loaded in the editor. I have to manually load it from the sources list. Is there any way to simultaneously open Dev tools and the file at the same time?

Comment: Normally I wouldn't want to view the current html page in sources.  It is more useful in the Elements view.  You can ensure going there by right-clicking and choosing "Inspect Element" on some part of the page.

Comment: Good point, but my motivation for the question also extends to .md files, in a note-taking / document-writing scenario it would be particularly convenient to be able to open and edit the source directly